# What is gameStats sqlite?

Tags: league-of-legends

Inside the League of Legends folder there is a gameStats sqlite file.

I know sqlite is a database, but what is this for?

Will changing the values affect the client side of the game?

Comment: Could you clarify a little and add some more info? Is this a website? A program? A file?

Comment: Modifying it is probably illegal and can lead to your account getting perma ban.

Comment: What purpose would you possible have for modifying a stats file in a multiplayer competitive game?

Comment: I was just wondering. If it would be editable and affect the game. Then it should be reported to riot.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the values of the gameclient won't make a difference as the files are hash checked whenever you play. An exception to this are the skins. It is possible to mount default skins as other paid skins, even though this is client side only and other players don't see your skin. None of the settings you can modify client side will impact the game.

Comment: Even though what you said is pretty clear, just to stress on it: Any modifications you make to the skins will be visible only to you.